why is my texture warping/stretching?
I have an issue with the texturing / UV wrapping of my UGC/model.
So First I made the links, used the array, then I made a Bezzier Circle Curved it.
I Smart UV Unwrap, then I Took the Islands and moved them to go on top of the Texture. Whenever I did this it ended up warping all the textures, whenever I move the Island it splits the texture. (displayed in the first picture.
This is my first time marking seams so im not completely sure on if i marked it in the right place or not.
How can I manage to have them all lined up to create a clean UV Map without warping the texture. If anyone has any tips or workflow ideas to circumvent this issue, or a whole idea how to avoid it that would be great. Thank you, im willing to do anything at this point.




https://blend-exchange.com/　Can you share the blender file so I only need the mesh for that part?Then someone may be able to answer more specifically.

i added the blend file to the original post.

it happens because they are twisted from their original shape, it makes the inner triangulation appear

@moonboots how do i properly morph the object without distorting the UV map/texture?

You can subdivide it, it will increase the number of faces though

@moonboots i need it to stay under 4k tris so is there another way i could it without subdividing? ive seen another model like that so i know you can do it i just dont know how

could you please point to the other model you're talking about?

@moonboots somebody helped me with it. thank you though!!

I've looked at your file.
when I went to the UVediting mode it seems like only part of your mesh is unwraped and the others are just broken and shrinked.

to fix this first go to [Edit mode] -select all of the mesh by pressing 'A' then 'p' -> 'Separate by loose parts'
I see that this was made by 'array' so what you are going to do is just Unwrap only one of the things you want to texture and Copy the UVMap to the others.

I have separated and Unwrapped the Two Chain parts.

Now just select the same parts you want to texture. But always Select the Unwrapped Object LAST.
Press Ctrl+L -> Copy UVMaps

Hope this helps :)

thank you so much!!! that really helped!

@Lora if the answer is correct, mark it as such   ;)

The easiest way is to use a smart UV project.
However, there are a few things you need to do to prepare.
The following is what you need to do.
1, APPLY the rotation and scale of the object.
]
]
If this is not done, distortion will occur when the UV map is expanded.
2、Do ten smart UV projects.
]
Even if you don't have a seam, this will easily expand the object.
If it's a complex object, it won't spread sometimes,
Install TEXTOOL from the add-on site,
Check for overlap.
]
If there is overlap, separate the mesh with a UV map.
If this is not done, strange streaks will form when baking.
]
If you want to create gaps automatically, you can create them in the Smart UV project options.
]
You can create the gap later with pack island.
3, Generate a test image to check the distortion. (last).
]
You can prepare your own image for this as well,
TeXTOOL is a convenient way to do this.
]
TexTools can be downloaded from the following link.
https://github.com/franMarz/TexTools-Blender
